# Is the scope in an Angular directive link function the same $scope in an angular directive controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Javascript:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('compileExample', compileExample);
  function compileExample() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        angular.element(tElement).append("My name is {{name}}");
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.name = "Liam";
      },
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>controllerVsLink</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <compile-Example></compile-Example>
</body>
</html>
```

This works the way I would expect it, compile runs first and appends that template to the element, than controller changes name to become Liam so the view shows "My name is Liam". From reading the Angular docs link also runs after compile so why is it when i change the controller to a link function name never gets updated or shown in the view?

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('compileExample', compileExample);
  function compileExample() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        angular.element(tElement).append("My name is {{name}}");
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.name = "Liam";
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: `scope { name : 'Liam' }` then call it in link function may be it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like if you have compile in the directive definition object, it disables any default post-link function that you specifiy outside the compile... link will only work with compile if is returned directly from the compile.. hopefully someone with more angular experience can elaborate

Comment: Yes and yes. The `$scope` injected in a directive controller is the same as the scope furnished as the first argument to the directive linking functions  both preLink and postLink. And yes, if you define a `compile` property in the DDO, then the `link` property is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

An important difference between the directive linking function and the directive controller function is the way arguments are furnished.

Controller function arguments are **injected by name**.

```
  //This will work
  controller: function($element, $scope) {
      $scope.name = "Liam";
  },

  //AND this will work
  controller: function($http, $scope, $element) {
       $scope.name = "Liam";
  },
```

The controller function arguments are furnished by the `$injector` service and include all the AngularJS services as well as the locals `$scope`, `$element`, `$attrs`, and `$transclude`.

Link function arguments are **furnished by position**.

```
  //This will work
  link: function(scope, element) {
    scope.name = "Liam";
  },

  //This will FAIL
  link: function(element, scope) {
    scope.name = "Liam";
  },
```

Link functions arguments are furnished by the `$compile` service **by position** and the names used by the arguments behave as function arguments normally do in JavaScript.

For more information on **injected locals**, see [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference -- controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-).

For more information on **injection by name**, see [this Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35493601/5535245).