# How does angular's controller method make $scope available to my function argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

*I am looking for a pseudo code answer, or conceptual answer please.*

---

After programming for a number of years I have never created a class method  that  receives a  function argument such that the caller of the method automatically gets access to 'invisible' properties.

If I try to access $scope outside of my `my_app.controller(...)` method, I get an error so I know it's not global; if I try to access it from `my_app.$scope` or `angular.$scope` I get undefined.

So how does my function parameter get access to it:

```
    my_app.controller('my_controller' , function( $scope , ... ) { ... }
```

---

UPDATE (as I am learning):

```
  // javascript
  var my_class =   function( argument_A )                 
                       { this.some_prop = argument_A ;        

                         this.some_method = function( argument_B ) 
                           { console.log( argument_B ) ; // function(boo)
                           } ;
                       } ;

  var my_instance = new my_class( "my_string" ) ;

  var my_function_argument = function( boo ){ } ;
  my_instance.some_method( my_function_argument ) ;
```

Comment: When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: I think that's my question: how to create an 'injectable parameter' ... maybe I need to google search it ... ... but I want to understand the concept well enough such that I should be able to do it with any other languages

Comment: This is called 'dependency injection', it does seem quite 'magical' the first time you experience it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Functions Are First Class Citizens

In JavaScript and other modern languages (Scala, Haskell, LISP, etc.), functions are treated as first-class citizens. Specifically, this means the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures. Some programming language theorists require support for anonymous functions (function literals) as well. In languages with first-class functions, the names of functions do not have any special status; they are treated like ordinary variables with a function type.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)</sup>

The above example can be re-factored as:

```
var myController = function ($scope, ... ) {
     console.log($scope);
     $scope.message = "Hello world"
};

my_app.controller('my_controller' , myController );
```

In this case the `.controller` method stores the `myController` object in the cache of the AngularJS `$controllerProvider` service. I.e. `cache["my_controller"] = myController;`

Later when the `$compile` service encounters a directive that needs a controller:

```
<div ng-controller="my_controller">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

The `$compile` service creates a new scope, retrieves the `myController` function from the `$controller` service cache, and invokes the function with the new scope as the first argument of the function.

The `$compile` service also creates a `$watch` listening function that tracks the `$scope.message` variable. On each digest cycle, if `$scope.message` has changed, the DOM is updated appropriately.

In the examples from the question:

```
//These are function invocations, the variable must be defined

console.log( boo )              ; //    ERROR: boo is not defined
my_instance.some_method( boo )  ; //    ERROR: boo is not defined
```

The last form uses an **anonymous function** literal (or function expression). The anonymous function is an object passed as an argument to the method named  `.some_method`.

```
//The anonymous function is an object passed as an argument
//boo is a parameter to be supplied when the function is invoked

my_instance.some_method( function( boo ) { } ) ; // NO ERROR
```

For more information on function literals, see [MDN JavaScript Reference -- function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function*).

---

### Dependency Injection and Connecting Arguments by Name

Normally in JavaScript, function arguments are connected **by position**. In the AngularJS framework, function arguments are injected **by name**. How is that done?

From the Docs:

> ### Inference
>
> In JavaScript calling `toString()` on a function returns the function definition. The definition can then be parsed and the function arguments can be extracted.

-- [AngularJS $injector Service API Reference -- Inference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#inference)

So in the example:

```
my_app.controller('my_controller' , function( $scope , ... ) { ... }
```

The `$injector` service does a `toString()` on the controller construction function and parses it. The service detects that `$scope` is the first argument of the function and uses that knowledge to invoke the function correctly.

You can see `fn.toString()` being used [here in the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L72).

Comment: this seems to be a part of the answer (maybe the 2nd part) ... but it seems that the first part is understanding how, out of nowhere, a variable can just be all of the sudden ... ... for instance, where did _$scope_ come from? why didn't it generate an error ... it is not global, it is not defined withing the scope of the most local container ... but apparently js (and apparently other languages) allow (intentionally? ... is it a mistake of the language? ... is there any kind of bleeding effect that can occur from this?) this type of syntax ...

Comment: `$scope` in this context is legal because until it's called, it is just part of the function definition; and guess what is calling this function? AngularJS...and it resolves the function definition to known entities within AngularJS's system (including `$scope`, Angular Services and Providers, as well as user defined Services).  It's not an error because the calling code knows what to 'inject' for the `$scope` variable.

Comment: See my explaination about functions as first class citizens.

Comment: the first code snippet in your FAFCC section really makes it so clear ... for some reason I was not seeing that ... but now I understand why the `boo` was not triggering an error ... thanks for taking the time to clarify ...

Comment: maybe I could suggest that you make FAFCC the 1st section of your answer, because it indicates why the previously-undeclared $scope is fair (because it is not even a variable ... it's an argument of an anonymous function) ... .... and the make the toString explanation the 2nd section of your answer, because it explains what happens after the class method (eg `.controller(...)`) does after it receives the anonymous function ...

Comment: I took your suggestion and re-ordered the sections of the answer. To me the method of connecting arguments **by name** instead of connecting **by position** is more mysterious. But I have embraced the concepts of functional programming for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

While you are creating a function and passing `dependency` name inside function parameter, in that case angular creates an object for each dependency by resolving that dependency from its DI container. This kind of dependency injection technique known as `constructor function`(there are two more DI techniques).

When you inject controller on DOM using `ng-controller` directive at that time function is passed to `$controllerProvider`'s [**`register`**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/controller.js#L38) function. controller function is known as factory function. Which will get passed with dependency as parameter. `$injector` service get each of dependency from function, and do `$injector.get` to return out what ever dependency is registered in DI container. While doing returning `$scope` dependency it creates out new `scope` from `rootScope` using `$rootScope.$new(isolate, parent)` method. `$new` method takes two parameter 1st one as `bool` & 2nd one as `parentScope` parameter. Other dependency directly taken out from register component to module.

Comment: I feel like this explains how it is handled once it has occurred, but I am mystified by how it actually occurs ...